# Changing background image on different pages

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask how to "lock" background img regardless of amount of text on page. I have 2 background imgs (1 in left, 1 in right). Over that is text article. On every page is different amount of text and imgs aren´t on same spot. If add `height: 100%` to `.pozadi` imgs locks out and are on the same spot on every page but in this case text overflows its parent element(`.pozadi`).

I am aware that giving webpage as example isn´t the best way because probably won´t be there unfix forever but I think that eg. I made below isn´t good enough.

http://matmasar.wz.cz/kompresory/kompresory.html I am talking about the helix in background. If you open page "prodej kompresorů" or "opravy kompresorů" you will probably understand my problem more.

The `sroubovice` is a attribute of `body` so I made a wrap div for example.

```css
  #primary_nav_wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


#sroubovice {
  background-image: url(http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/pozadi.png), url(http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/pozadi.png);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}


.tlacitka {
  color: white;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}


.pozadi {
  background: #e7f1f5;
  float: right;
  width: 76%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sroubovice">
  <img src="../fotky/zahlavi3.jpg" id="zahlavi">
  <article>
    <section>
      <h1>Prodej kompresorů</h1>
      <div id="wrap">
        <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
          <ul>
            <a href="../index.html">
              <li class="tlacitka" style="border-top-left-radius: 15px;">Domů</li>
            </a>
            <a href="kompresory.html">
              <li class="tlacitka">Kompresory</li>
            </a>
            <a href="opravy.html">
              <li class="tlacitka">Opravy kompresorů</li>
            </a>
            <a href="../kontakt.html">
              <li class="tlacitka" style=" border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; border-bottom: none;">Kontakt</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="pozadi">
          <br> Pokud Vám dosluhuje Vaše stávající kompresorová stanice nebo projektujete zcela novou instalaci stlačeného vzduchu, můžeme Vám nabídnout řešení s použitím velmi kvalitních kompresorů a dalšího příslušenství pro úpravu stlačeného vzduchu
          firem <a href="gardnerdenver.html">Gardner Denver</a> a <a href="compair.html">CompAir</a>.
          <a href="gardnerdenver.html">
            <img src="../fotky/gardnerdenver.png" alt="Gardner Denver logo" title="Gardner Denver logo" class="logo"></a>
          <a href="compair.html"><img src="../fotky/CompAir.png" alt="CompAir logo" title="CompAir logo" class="logo" style="margin-bottom: 50px;"></a>
          <ul style="font-weight: bold;">
            <li>Napište si o cenovou nabídku</li>
            <li>Společně zkonzultujeme Váš projekt a navrhneme ideální řešení.</li>
            <li>Neváhejte nás kontaktovat</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Konec div class pozadi -->
      </div>
      <!-- Konec div id wrap -->
```

Comment: Just don't make it `height:100%`?

Comment: How can I don´t make it height 100% when it is attribute of body as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution.

I removed `.pozadi` from `body` and replaced `article` with `div` as a first child element of `body`. So it looks like this

```
<body>
<div id="sroubovice">
<section>
....
</section>
</div>
</body>
```

Then added `height 100%` and `background-position: left top(or 140px for more exact result), right 140px` to `.pozadi`

```
#sroubovice{
background-image: url(../fotky/pozadi.png), url(../fotky/pozadi.png);
background-position: left 140px, right 140px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#sroubovice {
    background-position: center top;
}
```

Comment: Now it stays on the same spot on every page but I wanted it to have one img left and second on right as a background  behind the `.pozadi`. If I add `height: 100%;` to `.pozadi` it works as I want but in that case text overflows the `.pozadi`.